# Change of variables in a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In our textbook, we have the problem:

$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$ where $u(x,0)=g(x)$

We are told that the transformation $v=u_y$ transforms this PDE into:

$v_{xx}+v_{yy}=0$ where $v(x,0)=g(x)$

I am having trouble understanding how the textbook got this transformed PDE. I understand how we transformed the initial condition. Any guidance or tips would be much appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might want to check if there's any typo in your equations.

Comment: I double checked, and there doesn't seem to be any typos.

Comment: What book are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance I thought there must be a typo, but it turns out this works fine.  Letting $v = u_{y}$ and computing partial derivatives of $v$ gives us

$$\begin{align*}
v_{xx} &= u_{yxx}\\
v_{yy} &= u_{yyy}
\end{align*}
$$

Assuming symmetry of partial derivatives $$u_{yxx} = u_{xxy},$$

and so we have $$v_{xx} + v_{yy} = u_{xxy} + u_{yyy} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(u_{xx} + u_{yy}\right) = 0.$$

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help.